Why is `Prelude.mod` a total function?
Why is Prelude.mod marked as a total function when it is not defined when the second argument is zero?
Main> :total mod
Prelude.Num.mod is total

I was just bit by this and ran into a run-time error, even though Idris2 assured me my functions were total.

it's a known bug

I see. Don't you want to post it as an answer?
